# Direct Cache Access in Apollo Angular

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have the following service class:

```js
const DeleteUserMutation = gql `
 mutation($user_id: ID!) {
  deleteUser(id: $user_id) {
   id
  }
 }
`;

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  deleteUser(userId: string) {
    return this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: DeleteUserMutation,
      variables: {
        user_id: userId
      },
      update: (proxy, mutationResult) => {
        proxy.writeQuery({
          query: DeleteUserMutation,
          data: {
            deleteUser: {
              id: userId,
              __typename: 'User'
            }
          },
          variables: {
            user_id: userId
          }
        });
      },
    })
  }
}
```

whereby I'm trying to delete a user from my server. The mutation actually works and executes on the server successfully, but the cache never gets updated. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with my `update` part above.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to update a `Mutation` instead of a `Query` when this user lives.

Let's say you have this query:

```
query allUsers {
  users: [User]
}
```

To update the cache you would like to do something like this:

```
const DeleteUserMutation = gql `
    mutation($user_id: ID!) {
        deleteUser(id: $user_id) {
            id
        }
    }
`;

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  deleteUser(userId: string) {
    return this.apollo.mutate({
      mutation: DeleteUserMutation,
      variables: {
        user_id: userId
      },
      update: (proxy, { data: { deleteUser } }) => {
        // Get data from `allUsers` query
        const data = proxy.readQuery({
          query: AllUsersQuery
        });

        // Logic to remove an item from an array
        const users = removeUserFromArray(deleteUser.id, data.users);

        // write new array with users to the store
        proxy.writeQuery({
          query: AllUsersQuery,
          data: {
            users
          }
        });
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Take a look at the ["Updating the Store"](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#directAccess) chapter, the part with `update()` function in `react-angular` docs. Those rules apply for Angular too.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. But would that work even if the `allUsers` query was not the original query that resulted in that list of users being in the store in the first place?

Comment: So I tried, and the answer is no... I guess what I need can be resolved by `writeFragment` then?